# How to generate a querylist in Django, which needs to be generated only once?

Tags: python, django

I am developing a language website now and I have a Django view, called ExerciseView. My idea is next - go to the page (views triggers) --> querylist is generated in a random order --> declare sessions --> change them to dictionary to access easier --> and conditionals starts. My question is - how to generate the querylist only once and keep it the same until the training is finished. Every time a person clicks the buttons, new GET request is made and new querylist is generated. How can I make it constant and random list, which is not changing like that?

The first time it generates this
[<Exercise: Я пью чай без лимона >, <Exercise: Это дом папы >, <Exercise: У Тимофея день рождения сегодня!>]

The next time I make a POST request and then again GET happens and this querylist is already different:
[<Exercise: Я иду домой с работы >, <Exercise: Я пью чай без лимона >, <Exercise: У меня нет друга >]

class ExerciseView(View):

```
def get(self, request, **kwargs):
    data = list(Exercise.objects.filter(topic_type__slug=kwargs['slug_exercise']).all().order_by('?'))[:3]
    id = request.session.setdefault('sentence_id', 0)
    score = request.session.setdefault('score', 0)
    sentences = request.session.setdefault('sentences', {})
    for i in range(0, len(data)):
        sentences[i] = {
            'sentence': data[i].sentence,
            'correct_answer': data[i].correct_answer,
            'translation': data[i].translation,
            'initial_form': data[i].initial_form,
            'second_part': data[i].second_part
        }
    length = request.session.setdefault('length', len(sentences))
    if length == id:
        return render(request, 'practice_cases/exercise.html', {
            'message': 'You have just completed the test!',
            'score': score,
            'length': length,
        })
    else:
        if 'adjectives' in kwargs['slug_exercise'] or 'possessives' in kwargs['slug_exercise']:
            chosen_sentence = request.session.get('chosen_sentence', sentences[id]['sentence'])
            sentence_translation = request.session.get('sentence_translation', sentences[id]['translation'])
            initial_form = request.session.get('initial_form', sentences[id]['initial_form'])
            correct_answer = request.session.get('correct_answer', sentences[id]['correct_answer'])
            second_part = request.session.get('second_part', sentences[id]['second_part'])
            return render(request, 'practice_cases/exercise.html', {
                'sentence': chosen_sentence,
                'form': ExerciseForm(),
                'score': score,
                'length': length,
                'translation': sentence_translation,
                'initial_form': initial_form,
                'correct_answer': correct_answer,
                'second_part': second_part
        })
        else:
            chosen_sentence = request.session.get('chosen_sentence', sentences[id]['sentence'])
            sentence_translation = request.session.get('sentence_translation', sentences[id]['translation'])
            correct_answer = request.session.get('correct_answer', sentences[id]['correct_answer'])
            second_part = request.session.get('second_part', sentences[id]['second_part'])
            return render(request, 'practice_cases/exercise.html', {
                'sentence': chosen_sentence,
                'form': ExerciseForm(),
                'score': score,
                'length': length,
                'translation': sentence_translation,
                'correct_answer': correct_answer,
                'second_part': second_part
        })
```

I have tried to convert it to tuple, make a method in the class but nothing seems to work so far.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to reach the goal.

1. We need to write a query (doesn't matter with filter or simple)
2. Add values() and fill fields to be fetched.
3. Convert the whole queryset to list()

```
data = request.session.setdefault('exercises_data', list(Exercise.objects.filter(topic_type__slug=kwargs['slug_exercise']).all().order_by('?').values('sentence', 'correct_answer', 'initial_form', 'second_part', 'translation')))
```